# Not able to use UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am new to iOS so please bear with me if this is a basic question. I am following [these tutorials](https://www.udemy.com/complete-ios-developer-course/) and in lecture 43, the guy deletes the existing view controller and adds a new view controller. Then he inserts a table view (from the storyboard), command clicks on the table view and assigns the dataSource and delegate to the view controller.

Then in the ViewController.swift file, `UITableViewDelegate` is added so that it looks like

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate{

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Then he command clicks on UITableViewDelegate to copy these two functions:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

Now! These are the problems that I am facing:

1) When I write UITableViewDelegate, there is no auto complete (which suggests something is wrong)

2) When I command click on UITableViewDelegate, it says **Symbol not found** (so I cannot get the above functions)

Would massively appreciate any help please.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where did you write those ? Cras is due to you didn't implemented those datasource methods. Can you add an image of the issue ?

Comment: in the ViewController.swift file. Problem 1) is just a lack of autocomplete and for problem 2) I cannot take a screenshot when  Iam command clicking on UITableViewDelegate

Comment: screeshot of your viewontroller swift problem for identifying the auto completion issue

Comment: Sorry the video quality (of the tutorial) is not that great but it is meant to be autocompleting like this:
http://s28.postimg.org/kkyxvq3r1/Screen_Shot_2015_01_02_at_01_12_19.png

and when I do it, the autocomplete does not come up. As a result, I am unable to command click on it to retrieve the functions as written above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into XCode preferences > Locations > Then under the Derived Data TextField there is an arrow. Click that. Then delete your DerivedData folder and relaunch XCode. This may fix your auto complete, as it constantly crashes for some reason. Whenever autocomplete isn't working for me I just delete DerivedData and it usually works again.

Comment: Sweeet! Works like a charm! Thank you very much! How did you know to do that just out of interest?

Comment: I took an app development class last semester in college and that's how my professor recommended fixing it.

Comment: Thanks once again buddy. Happy NY to you :)